# Cross queries in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models as below

```
class Watched(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=None)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Link(Stamping):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
    watched = models.ForeignKey(Watched, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    ...
```

My forms.py

```
class SimpleLink(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=256)
```

A user can create a `Link` object and when some conditions are met, the object will be added to `Watched`. The `Watched` model contains objects created by different users.
Now I want to filter the `Watched` class and grab only the objects created by the requesting user in the `Link` model but I don't know how I can achieve that. Any help will be appreciated.
A sample of what I want to achieve is...
`Watched.objects.filter(Link.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. I know my sample is crazy. But from the outside query, I want to grab the Link objects created by user making the request

Comment: Can you share your current form?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the form

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the queryset in your `ModelForm`. A `ModelForm` will thus look like:

```
from django import forms

class LinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['watched'].queryset = Watched.objects.filter(
                link__user=user
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['url', 'watched']
```

In our view, we can then set the `user` object:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LinkForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-form')
    else:
        form = LinkForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

For a *class-based view*, we can override the [**`.get_form_kwargs(…)`** method [Djangod-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = LinkForm
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: In my view, is there a way I can do something like ```Watched.objects.filter(Link.objects.filter(user=request.user)```. I know my sample is crazy. But from the outside query, I want to grab the ```Link``` objects created by user making the request

Comment: @Sammy: yes, you can filter with `Watched.objects.filter(link__user=request.user)`. This will thus retrieve all `Watched` objects for which a *related* `Link` exists with as `user` the `request.user`.

Comment: I this should be added as an answer so that I can mark it

Comment: @Sammy: updated the filtering in the modelform.